# Read csv with network and subnetmask and write a file with ping results

Tags: python, string, loops, networking, ping

I'm trying to create a python script that will read from a files.csv file with this format:

```
10.0.20.0,255.255.255.0
192.168.10.0,255.255.252.0
```

It will calculate that subet and loop and ping all ip addresses on that subnet and write to a file,  example  10.0.20.0.txt with the results of the ping  (reachale or not reachable). I'm having trouble with the subnet calculator and how to loop and ping the last octet: 10.0.20.1, 10.0.20.2, 10.0.20.3, etc...

Comment: We are happy to help you, but we're not a code writing service nor a replacement for basic tutorials and documentation. Show us your code, explain specifically what you're having a hard time with, and we can probably help you out.

Comment: As suggested by @larsks, you have to try something before ask a question. The code below is good start point to do what you want:

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @martineau and @larsks, you have to try something before ask a question. The code below is good start point to do what you want:

```
import ipaddress

address = '10.0.20.0'
netmask = '255.255.255.0'

ipv4 = ipaddress.IPv4Network(f'{address}/{netmask}')

for ip in list(ipv4)[1:-1]:
    print(ip)
```

Then install the [`icmplib`](https://github.com/ValentinBELYN/icmplib) and use the `ping` function (`pip install icmplib`). To save data to csv, use the modul `csv`.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you more help.

Comment: how to using ping function? i was importing os and using the regular ping command line , but i want this to be portable to any os